# fullPage.js not scrolling / no scroll possible

Tags: javascript, scroll, vertical-scrolling, fullpage.js

I've been having this issue with fullpage.js not allowing me to scroll properly. Please see the issue at https://www.rewardslive.com/test

I have jQuery 1.10 loaded onto the site already, but the javascript code that is in question here is inline on the page, after  along with the initialization code which is an extension of the document ready with no conflict in the rewardslive.js inline script.

Going to the page does not pose an issue, but when i try to scroll down, the url bar changes to https://www.rewardslive.com/test#secondPage - but there is no actual scrolling downward and no new content is updated. I want to keep the header as seen, in there for all intents and purposes.

Is there something I am missing here? All i want is the basic fullpage, 'scroll down function to see more' feature.

Thanks again,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javascript console shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'easeInQuart'

Which means you are not importing the jQuery UI library which is needed by the plugin as specified [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you have problems in your HTML markup as you can see highlighted in red [here](http://jsfiddle.net/584yP/).

If you do not want to include the whole jquery UI library for just that single effect, you can use the [easings file provided by fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js) that includes all of the jquery UI easings.

Comment: I added in the jQuery UI, but it seems to break the rest of the site and make it all become plain text instead of having the plugin work... Any ideas? I just dropped the jquery ui in there.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Please take the source code of the [live demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) as an example (or any of the other online examples) and from there add your stuff.

Comment: Would there be an issue if I had 3 versions of jQuery at once? I had 1.4.1 which is required for one of my legacy js apps, 1.10.2 which is the one I use primarily. I don't know if fullpage.js only supports 1.8.3, but i've been using 1.10.2 the entire time for everything else. Sorry for the confusion.. I'm not that good at javascript. Perhaps it's a conflict with my other javascript? I'll try your method and report back!~

Comment: You should only be using one. Fullpage supports from 1.8.3 and on.

Comment: what javascript console are you using?

Comment: Chrome inspector. But I didn't need the console to see that your code is not in the right place.

Comment: I got it to work now, just removed the second instance of jquery 1.8.3! yay! thanks so much :)

Comment: One last thing: i'm trying to get the background image thing to work, but the image seems to be stretching too large - i'm using the example on the http://alvarotrigo.com site. Can you please take a look? it's the same link rewardslive.com/test

Comment: Oops, that was just the CSS - i just needed to remove the padding :) Answer has been accepted! thanks!